# Django: How can I use templating to add a header to each HTML page, and only update one central file?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have about 12 different HTML pages in my Django application. I am looking for a way to make my header in 1 template file, and then add that file to each HTML template that I need a header on.

I tried following the template documentation from Django, but it wasn't concise enough for me. Would anyone be able to please break it down a little further for me?

I am basically starting at square 1 with this... I was at a point where I was able to get a header to load, but no css was attached to it. I have since erased the code because I didn't want to screw anything up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this.

**1. Make an outer file and insert all your code into the inner file. This uses extends.**

The outer file, base.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
</head>


<style>
body { padding-top: 70px;
        font-family: Poppins;
     }

</style>
<body>
 <navbar> This is your Navbar. Navbar does assume the use of Bootstrap</navbar>

<p> You can also put anything else you want on every page here.</p>
    <main role="main" class="container">
     {% block content %}
     {% endblock %}
        </main>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The inner file, page.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>This is the stuff you want to be unique to the page. </p>
{% endblock %}
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you are essentially putting one page inside another and it is a little less flexible.

**2. Include the chunk of code inside an HTML file. This uses include.**

The page you want to add the header to, page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
</head>


<style>
body { padding-top: 70px;
        font-family: Poppins;
     }

</style>
<body>
    {% include "header.html" %}

    <main role="main" class="container">
<p> Whatever you want on your page</p>

        </main>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The actual code for your header, header.html

```
<div class="header">
  <p>My supercool header</p>
</div>
```

Include will insert that block of HTML code right where you put the include statement.

Comment: Man, I may have been looking at the docs all wrong, but so far, this is the most concise I've seen. The `extends` is what was killing me. Would I be able to place a link to my CSS file inside of the `header.html` file? Or do I have to place my style plainly inside of the `header.html` file?

Comment: Worth noting also: If using includes, you can pass a variable to the include file: `{% include "header.html" with nav=someVariable %}` This means if you pass `someVariable` from your view function, you can then access this in `header.html` as `{{nav}}`.  This is useful for dynamically building the header bar, or a nav bar.

Comment: Docs are usually a bit light on examples, which is something I find quite annoying. :) You should be able to place the link to the CSS directly inside the header.html file. The thing to keep in mind is that the entire chunk of code is being inserted into the main page, so anything in the header CSS could apply to the rest of the page as well.

Comment: @v25 thanks, dude! That's really good info to have... @Matthew Gaiser , I have specific identifiers for my header for just this reason. I'm actually using `SASS` and just include the `header.scss` into each subsequent files .scss file. Thanks a bunch! I'll report back when I test this out

Comment: Side node for relative files. Using `{% include "header.html" %}` might throw a `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: header.html` error. To solve it, assuming `header.html` is in the same dir, do `{% include "./header.html" %}`.

Comment: A bit late, but is the include approach possible if I want to share a header between apps on the same website? Meaning that `mysite/app1` and `mysite/app2` share some template files (like header, footer,...). In that case, how would the `{% include "header.html" %}` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to define a block in base.html and then you can define your header and footer in other HTML files.

```
<header>...</header>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<footer>...</footer>
```

Later you can use this block content in any other html pages as follows,

```
{% extends "public/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Header or Footer content goes here</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Now breaking it down for you,
1. Re-using a common chunk of code in multiple places in your webapp front end requires you to use extending templates feature in django
2. You can create the common content in your base.html file and define it inside a block content as shown above
3. Now you can connect other HTML files with the base.html by using {% extends "public/base.html" %} at the top of your HTML file.
4. You can re-use the block content defined in base.html in current html file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It gets to the point and is clear. I think I like Matthew's `include` portion, I will give both of these a test...